# Is timestamp field mandatory in druid

Tags: druid

I have a csv dataset without timestamp field is it possible to upload that csv file without that field. I have tried doing it but its not working. I added timestamp field to a sample dataset and it worked!. Is timestamp field mandatory for druid datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need a time column, druid uses such a column as a way to index the data. So a fake time column should be enough to trick druid BUT BUT
If your data and query workload do not include time, druid is not your best tool thought!!

Answer (score 0):

Although every druid datasource will have a `__time` column, **source data do not require temporal columns to be ingested**. You can define a spec that adds a column and sets a default timestamp. You do this within the timestampSpec:

```
"timestampSpec": {
    "column": "default_timestamp",
    "format": "auto",
    "missingValue": "1970-01-01"
}
```

this timestampSpec will add a new column called `default_timestamp` who's values will be set to `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.

Note: the column `default_timestamp` will immediately be renamed to `__time`.

[docs](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/ingestion-spec.html#timestampspec)